# ocaml boolean define a function that contains an element return true if so or else false

Tags: if-statement, ocaml

I am not sure why this is throwing me an error. Any help is appreciated thank you! The question is: "Define a function contains taking an element and a list and returning true if the element is in the list, and false otherwise."

My answer is:

```
let contains elt l = 
    if l = l
      then true
    else
      false;;
```

It is saying that everything is true when I test it.

UPDATE:

I think this is closer to the answer but still cannot get it working.

```
    let rec contains elt l = 
      if 
        elt = l
        l = []
      then true
      else
      false;;
```

Comment: What's your reasoning for this implementation? When do you expect `l` to not equal itself?

Comment: my idea for this implementation is that  if l is in the list then it will equal true but if it is not found in the list it will return false, but after reading more into it i understand it does not make sense because it is just saying l is equal to l so that will always be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's apply your function to `5`, here is how the computer will reduce/evaluate your code:

```
 contains elt 5 => if 5 = 5 then true else false
```

obviously `5` will be always equal to `5`. Moreover, the variable will always be equal to itself.

Tip 1: you're not using the first parameter

Tip 2: the second parameter is meant to be a list of elements in which you should search the first parameter

Tip 3: you need to use recursion and deconstruct the second parameter and compare each element of a list with the provided `elt` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see that l = l is just stating that l is always going to be true there for it will never goto false and that I also did not search for l inside of the list!

Comment: is this sort of the idea? let rec contains elt l = 
  if 
    let elt = l
    let l = [elt]
  then true
  else
  false;;

Comment: nay, you shall (a) deconstruct your list using the `match/with` construct, test, and then recursively call on the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
    let contains elt l = 
      match l with
      [] -> false
      | y :: ys -> elt = y || contains elt ys
      ;;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you forgot to add `rec` after `let`